# Detecting Guest to Guest Traffic in Virtualbox Using Host Running Snort

Tags: penetration-test, snort, sniffing

Not sure if this is a simple question but I was hoping for some insight into finishing a pentest lab. My goal is to have Snort sniff an attack in a virtual environment between two guest VM's. My current setup running on virtualbox:

1. Windows 10 running Snort (host)
2. Kali as attacker (guest)
3. Unpatched Windows XP as target (guest)

The two guest machines are networked as host-only. Within each machine I can ping host-guest and guest-guest.Pinging host-guest and running a test ICMP alert [alert icmp any any -> any any (msg:"Testing ICMP"; sid:1000001;)] shows only the return echo packets. Pinging guest-guest does not show any traffic.

My Snort startup is:

```
C:\Snort\bin>snort -i 6 -c c:\snort\etc\snort.conf -A console
```

where 6 is the virtualBox interface

Keeping the same configuration but changing the interface to the host NIC and pinging the web from the host, Snort will display the ICMP request and replies.

Would this be a conf file issue or virtualbox network issue? Any insight into how I can have Snort monitor the traffic between the two guest while running on the host?

Thanks!